# Create a link external in botframework sdk nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, bots

I'm trying to create an external link in a dialog, and I'm not sure how to do that. Today I'm doing it this way, would it be the right way?

**BotBuilder 3.14 / SDK NodeJS**

```
bot.dialog('/history', (session) => {
    session.send('Want to know more about the story?')
    session.send(new builder.Message(session)
        .attachments([
            new builder.HeroCard(session)
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, 'web-site.com', 'Access')
                ])
        ]))
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: thanks @GaryLiu-MSFT